# Odoo shows only one type of taxes on out_refund tax lines, but should be more there

Tags: odoo-8, odoo, odoo-accounting

Client refunds (out_refund) show only one type of Tax in the tax list, even if there should be more than one.  For example: I have this out refund lines: One `S_IVA10B` and other with `S_IVA21B`

[image]

You can see `S_IVA21B` and `S_IVA10B`, right? Well... if you go to Other information tab, you find only one tax line:

[image]

Any of you know why this is happening (only) on refunds? The out_invoice elements are correct.

Comment: If the list is different then there is a domain check it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your comment. two screenshots belongs to the same out_refund: product list and tax list. It doesn't happen with the same tax in each case. It use to show the firs tax in invoice lines.

Comment: @CherifOdoo is trying to tell you, check if your tax field has some `domain` in its attributes, it could be the reason why you just show one type of taxes.

Comment: I have checked if there is a domain, as @CherifOdoo suggests, but I haven't found anything. I have another view where I show different taxes in columns and it shows values for each column for out_invocies (if it has to) except with out_refunds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a reported bug. Now it is solved in this commit: https://github.com/OCA/l10n-spain/commit/4ac7266648aab0fa469ae271a7541f6bec79f3fb
For unknown reason it haven't worked for me, but there is an official fix.